# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: don't understand why

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

```
import java.util.Random; // random class

public class MartianBattler { // start of class
    public static void main(String[] args) { // start of main
        int battles = 0; //initializes battles to 0
        Random rand = new Random(); // creates an object of random class

        int[] squad = new int[rand.nextInt(5)+1]; // generates a random number to tell us how many squads we will have    
        battles = rand.nextInt((5)+1); // generates number of battles to fight
        createSquad(squad);
        battle(squad, battles); // passes array squads elements to battle static    method
    } // end of main

    public static void battle(int[] squad, int battle) { // static method that sends troops to battle
        for(int x = 0; x < battle; x++ ) { // for loop
            Random randS = new Random(); // generate random object
            int first = randS.nextInt(squad.length)+1; // generate first martian to go
             System.out.printf("%d%n %d%n%d%n", squad.length, first, battle);
        }
    }

    public static void createSquad(int[] squad) {
        Random ramdS = new Random(); 

        MartianAttack foo = new MartianAttack(0,false); 
        boolean clone = false;
        for(int x = 0; x <= squad.length; x++)
        {
            clone = ramdS.nextBoolean();
            if (clone == true)
                squad[x] = foo.getidNumber();
            else 
                squad[x] = ramdS.nextInt((100)+1);
        }
    }
} // end of class

run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
    at MartianBattler.createSquad(MartianBattler.java:48)
    at MartianBattler.main(MartianBattler.java:12)
C:\Users\Ethan\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

I don't understand why my array is coming to a problem when filling in the array elements during the `for` loop in my `createSquad` method. It's not letting me pass the array into the `createSquad` method.. why? I've tried everything from reformatting the x in the `createSquad` method to an integer but I still don't get anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Your for loop `for (int x = 0; x <= squad.length; x++)` should be changed to `for (int x = 0; x < squad.length; x++)`

Arrays or 0-based in Java so you when x = 3 and the array is of size 3 you get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Try using a debugger in your IDE.

Comment: Thanks that was the answer! Somehow I forgot that array[3] only goes up to array[2] when printing or storing.... THANKS!